# Check for non existing data from external API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

I am calling an *external API* and it gives response like below which I am using in my code

```
    {
    "totalInvestedAmount": 10500.0,
    "totalCurrentValue": 10550.0,
    "otherInfo": {
             "firstData" : [             
                        "hi",
                        "hello",
                        "bye"
                   ],
           
              "secondData": "secondData",
              "thirdData": {
                         "a": "aaa",
                         "b": "bbb"
                     }
              }

}
```

**otherInfo** is an object which has **firstData**(String[]) and **secondData**(String).

Till now, the above response used to be come in this way that if **firstData** or **secondData** used to be **empty** in the response, it would look like

```
 {
    "totalInvestedAmount": 10500.0,
    "totalCurrentValue": 10550.0,
    "otherInfo": {
             "firstData" : [ "", ""],           
              "secondData": ""
}
```

I have checks like **Objects::nonNull** for **otherInfo** object and **secondData** in my code.

**NEW CHANGES IN THE RESPONSE OF EXTERNAL API**

But from now on, due to some changes in the external api system, the response would start coming like-

If **firstData** would contain empty values or **secondData** is **empty**, then the response will not contain these fields.

**Eg1**. If **firstData** contains empty values. Response would be

```
{
    "totalInvestedAmount": 10500.0,
    "totalCurrentValue": 10550.0,
    "otherInfo": {           
              "secondData": "sample text"
}
```

**Eg2** If **secondData** is empty, then response would be

```
{
    "totalInvestedAmount": 10500.0,
    "totalCurrentValue": 10550.0,
    "otherInfo": {           
              "firstData": [ "word1", "word2"]
}
```

**Eg3** If **firstData** and **secondData** - both would be empty then, response will not contain the **otherInfo** object. It would be like this:

```
 {
    "totalInvestedAmount": 10500.0,
    "totalCurrentValue": 10550.0,
  
}
```

So, I wanted to ask what type of checks should I include now in my code which can work with the above three examples. Please please drop a sample solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields which are not getting returned are null. So, Objects.isNull/nonNull check will work for these fields